# Change Array values to json format in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have an array like this

```
Array
            (
                [0] => [{"qty":"4023","discount":"-288.84000194072723"}]
                [1] => [{"qty":"48","discount":"-1"}]
                [2] => [{"qty":"305","discount":"0"}]
            )
```

How to convert these array to my format like

```
 [{"name":"qty","data":[4023,48,305]},{"name":"discount","data":[-288.84,-1,0]}]
```

**How to solve this problem?**

Comment: You know about http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php?

Comment: want us to google that for you?

Comment: I posted my solution for you problem, doesnt it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full solution (using `json_encode` and `json_decode`):

```
$array = array(
  '[{"qty":"4023","discount":"-288.84000194072723"}]',
  '[{"qty":"48","discount":"-1"}]',
  '[{"qty":"305","discount":"0"}]'
);

$new = array(
  (object) array("name" => "qty", "data" => array()),
  (object) array("name" => "discount", "data" => array())
);

foreach($array as $key => $value){
  $object = json_decode($value)[0];

  $new[0]->data[] = $object->qty ;
  $new[1]->data[] = $object->discount ;
}


$desired_result = json_encode($new);
var_dump($desired_result);
```

Sandbox for testing: ***[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eda841b834ce96b5d1ea3791d5eff2b88ca29d3d)***

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Example from PHP.net:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Output:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```